# What's the difference between the different Jersey test containers?

Tags: unit-testing, jersey

According to http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core/com/sun/jersey/test/framework/JerseyTest.html users may choose between two kinds of test containers:

1. Low-level container that does not support servlets
2. Web-based container that does support servlets

I have the following questions:

1. What's the advantage/disadvantage of each kind of container? For example, I assume low-level containers are faster but are missing some sort of functionality.
2. What is meant by the fact that low-level containers do not support servlets? I thought that JAX-RS is based on top of Servlets. What aren't low-level containers able to do?

**UPDATE**:

Upon further research I discovered that low-level containers are faster but they really run without servlets. When clients make requests,a the appropriate Resources are constructed and the response is passed back to the client, all in-memory. This is similar to running an embedded database versus a conventional network-based JDBC connection.

There is no mechanism to supply a ServletContextListener, register servlets or filters. I'm guessing the request scope isn't supported either.

My question is, can you really test anything meaningful under these restrictions?

Comment: Jersey uses in-memory container to test itself, so we already have this functionality and we are just exposing that. Any application not depending on Servlet can use that for its tests (not everything uses servlet).. so.. I don't really see why are you asking - you don't need to use that if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: @PavelBucek, I guess I'm asking for an example of what can be tested without servlets. Can you provide a real-world example?

Comment: @PavelBucek, so for example, does "any application not depending on Servlet" mean that I would not be able to have HttpServletRequest as a parameter to a web service method if I were testing said method with the in-memory container?  I assume so, just confirming.

Comment: @PaulD.Eden yep, thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

"... can you really test anything meaningful under these restrictions..."

You can test your business logic, and do it quicker.

(Would like to see this fixed though: [JERSEY-622](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-622?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel). The in-memory test container doesn't support Jackson, i.e. the POJO-mapping feature of Jersey.)

Comment: What's the point of testing your business logic without any web-related context (@RequestScoped or HttpServletRequest)? Wouldn't it be faster/easier to just test that code without Jersey using plain JUnit?

Comment: I've found that the most useful kind of test for the Jersey-based server project that I'm working on is to use the Jersey Client in JUnit tests to step through typical client interactions with the server, i.e. "log in and retrieve a list of resource X", "change the password for user Y", "add new instances of resource Z, browse the list of Zs, make sure the new ones are there", etc.

For each test I spin up an embedded Jetty server, Spring, an in-memory DB (Derby) and the relevant Jersey resources. Once the test run is warmed up then each test runs in maybe 0.5s each, which I'm fine with.

Comment: To answer your question: yes it would be easier to test the JAX-RS resource classes directly without bringing Jersey into the picture, but I find it useful to express the client tests in terms of the proper URLs, using the proper MIME types, etc.